# cross domain data submission

Tags: php, jquery, forms, cross-domain

I have two domains A.com and B.com

On A.com there are 2 files

> ```
> 1.form.html,-with form fields with action insert.php
> 2.insert.php-contains php code to store data on database
> ```

On B.com there is one file

> 1.data.php-contains php code to store data on database

On domain A with form.html,there is a form which ask user for personal details with name, email, address, and hobby. But when user fill up data into email field,**strong text** @ backside only email data directly stored at B.com via requesting to data.php page, and this does not effect on flow of data submission from form.html to insert.php.

is it possible with the help of php with jquery?can any one suggest me similar tutorial ?

Comment: Do you have access to both domains?

Comment: srry for not including, I have access to only B.com..